# Mysqli query not working - no error message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Right now I could not figure out what is wrong when I try to query a table at my mysql-server. Did I miss something crucial?

I want to get the last date in the table that is in the column after the primary key id.

*No error-message are appearing but when I echo the date no value are printed.*

thanks in advance!!!

```
 function query_last_date() {

    $query = "SELECT datum FROM omx_stockhom_30 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

    while(list($date) = $result->fetch_row());

    echo "date: ".$date;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump` all vars in this code and see what's going wrong

Comment: there should first parameter of connection varaible to your database in mysqli->query($conn,$query,mode)

Comment: @uvais - the code is using the object-oriented style. You only need the connection if you're using the procedural style: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!!!!

```
    function query_last_date() {

     $query = "SELECT datum FROM omx_stockhom_30 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

     $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

     while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))

     $lastDate = $row[0];

     echo "date: ".$lastDate;
    }
```

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Yes, but not if I change the query to cycle through the whole table.

Comment: Not to mention that your current approach has no essential difference from old one. So - it cannot be count as a "solution"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

and change your php.ini configuration to see all of the errors.
You can search your apache or nginx server error.log file to find what is the problem with your request or with another thing.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 $result = $this->mysqli->query(<yourconnectionvariable>,$query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 possible causes for the empty output.

1. You have no error reporting on - so, in this case you will obviously see no error
2. There is no data in the table to meet the query.

Check both.

Comment: But despite that - is my syntax correct? I have checked the name of the table and column names. I I have data in the table. Have no problem to upload data but to query data - no success!

Comment: Please, don't ask *humans* if your syntax correct. It's intended for the computer - so you have to ask a computer. *IF* computer says it's wrong - its time to ask humans, providing an error message. As long as a computer has no objections, don't bother yourself too.